# JavaFX button gives error when button text is clicked

Tags: java, button, javafx

I have a 4 buttons that when clicked, give an error when I click on the text of the button, but when I click on the button portion without text it works.

Here is the event code:

```
@FXML
public void starClick(MouseEvent event){
    event.consume();
    try{
        Button btn = (Button)event.getTarget();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //UIActions.setStarClick(Integer.parseInt(btn.getText()));
}
```

Here is the XML of one of the buttons:

```
<Button fx:id="star1" disable="false" focusTraversable="false" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#starClick" onMouseEntered="#starHover" onMouseExited="#starExit" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="25.0" styleClass="button-star" text="1" textFill="TRANSPARENT" visible="true">
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@../css/button.css" />
  </stylesheets>
</Button>
```

Here is the output when clicked:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledText cannot be cast to javafx.scene.control.Button
        at phantom.DocumentController.starClick(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1763)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1651)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3456)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8300(Scene.java:3387)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3755)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3471)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1695)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2486)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:314)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:243)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:345)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:526)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:898)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Does `event.getSource()` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure of the exact reason, but may be, the error is caused because the `Label` on the `Button` is also calling the same method. Have you tried using

```
onAction="#starClick"
```

instead of

```
onMouseClicked="#starClick"
```